# shiny error: unused arguments (main = "Smear plot", de.tags = dgeChangedGenes())

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to modularize a shiny app but I don't get what the problem is whith this error:

`error: unused arguments (main = "Smear plot", de.tags = dgeChangedGenes())`

Here is my code:

```
### UI
### -------------------------------------------------------------------- ###
plotSmearOutput <- function(id) {
  # Create a namespace function using the provided id
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(plotOutput(ns("deSmear"))),
    br(),
    fluidRow(actionButton(ns("runGlimmaSmear"), label = "Glimma Smear"))
  )
}


### SERVER
### -------------------------------------------------------------------- ###
plotSmear <- function(input, output, session, lrtModel, dgeChangedGenes) {

  output$deSmear <- renderPlot({
    # print(dgeChangedGenes())
    if(!is.null(lrtModel())){
    plotSmear(lrtModel(), main = "Smear plot", de.tags = dgeChangedGenes())
    }
  })

}
```

`lrtModel` and `dgeChangedGenes` are reactive values created by another module.`

`plotSmear` is a function from the `edgeR`package.

I tried to check if I could have a missing or extra parenthesis or bracket but either I haven't found it or I just don't have any.

Do you know what the problem could be here ?

Thank a lot.

Comment: What version of `edgeR` do you have installed? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You are calling a function plotSmear within the function with the same name plotSmear... I can see that you are writing a module, but surely this is not intended?